# Changing class with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following menu and I want to add a class 'active' to the last clicked link. Using native javascript not with JQuery.

Firstly, I'm removing active from all links then trying to add 'active' to clicked link

Here's what I'm trying but simply does nothing:

```
<a href="#" class="menu active" onclick="changeClass()">test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="menu" onclick="changeClass()">test 2</a>
<a href="#" class="menu" onclick="changeClass()">test 3</a>

function changeClass() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('menu').classList.remove('active');
  this.className('menu active');
}
```

[Here's a fiddle to have a look at but not if jsfiddle is working correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/xfh3bb0y/)

Comment: Try this answer to the same/similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`className` is not a function, so this line:

```
this.className('menu active');
```

causes an error you can readily see in the web console.

As you're using `classList` elsewhere, you could do:

```
this.classList.add('active');
```

Alternately, completely overwrite the classes:

```
this.className = 'menu active';
```

(Note that older browsers don't have `classList`, so for them you'll need a shim if you rely on it.)

Separately, `this` within your function will not be the element that was clicked, because of the way you have the event handler hooked up. You can ensure that it is `this` with a minimal change using `call`:

```
<a href="#" class="menu active" onclick="changeClass.call(this)">test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="menu" onclick="changeClass.call(this)">test 2</a>
<a href="#" class="menu" onclick="changeClass.call(this)">test 3</a>
```

You might even want to pass the event in:

```
<a href="#" class="menu active" onclick="changeClass.call(this, event)">test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="menu" onclick="changeClass.call(this, event)">test 2</a>
<a href="#" class="menu" onclick="changeClass.call(this, event)">test 3</a>
```

Or of course use modern techniques to hook up the handlers instead of attributes.

Comment: @Pointy: Good catch! No, it isn't. *Update*: I've updated the answer to deal with that, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

className is a property, not a method, so you should use it like this:

```
this.className = 'menu active'
```

And be aware that classList works in IE10+, and not below.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

`document.getElementsByClassName` does **not** return a single element, but an `HTMLCollection`, which is basically an array with additional properties. This means that you have to iterate over it in order to remove "active" from the classlists of all included elements.

```
var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("menu"),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    collection[i].classList.remove("active");
}
```

`this` does **not** point to the element you clicked on, but to the window object. In order to use the event target in your function, you have to pass it as a parameter inside the HTML code and use this parameter inside your function.

```
<a href="#" class="menu active" onclick="changeClass(this)">test 1</a>
...

function changeClass(target) {
    ...
    target.classList.add("active");
}
```

As you can see in the code above, you can also use `Element.classList.add` to add a class to your element. If you use `classList` in one case, you should probably use it in all cases. Older browsers do not support this feature, though. If you want to write backwards compatible code, you can use the `className` attribute.

```
collection[i].className = "menu"; // Removing the action class

target.className = "menu active"; // Adding the action class
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems:

**1.** `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which has no `classList` property. You have to access the items within the collection in order to access *their* properties, i.e.:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0].classList = "foo";
```

**2.** `Element.className` is a property, not a function. You must assign a value like so:

```
this.className = 'menu active';
```

**3.** When you attach a handler using inline markup, i.e.: `<a onclick="foo()">`, `this` (in the context of `foo`) is not the element that raised the event; it's the global object, [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). You might consider attaching those handlers programmatically instead ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ebswrtj/2)):

```
function menuClickHandler(e) {
    // on click...
    // if the event target is already active, return
    if (this.classList.contains("active")) return;
    // if the event target is not already active...
    // get an element that has both menu and active classes
    // apparently only one item is active at any time
    var active = document.querySelector(".menu.active");
    // did we find an item? remove the active class
    active && active.classList.remove("active");
    // add the active class to the event target, "this"
    // which is actually the appropriate element now
    this.classList.add("active");
}
// iterate over all menu items
[...document.querySelectorAll(".menu")].forEach(item =>
    // add a click handler to each item
    item.addEventListener("click", menuClickHandler)
);
```

<sub>See also: `document.querySelector()`, `document.querySelectorAll()`, `Array.prototype.forEach()`, and `EventTarget.addEventListener()`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the element on the onclick event and then change the class using the .className

HTML Code

```
<a href="#" class="menu active" onclick="changeClass(this)">test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="menu" onclick="changeClass(this)">test 2</a>
<a href="#" class="menu" onclick="changeClass(this)">test 3</a>
```

JS Code

```
function changeClass(elm) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
  elements[0].className = "menu";
  elm.className = 'menu active';
}
```